# How to generate positive numbers using repeat in R

Tags: r, function, repeat

I wrote the code below. The aim is to obtain positive numbers only. So, `rnorm(5,2,2)` can produce negative numbers too, but I want it to produce positive ones only. To do so, I used `repeat` in `R`, but it does not work properly. What can you suggest for fixing it? Here is the code:

```
for (i in 1:5){
repeat{
x <- rnorm(5,2,2)
if ((length(which(x<0)))==0){break}
print(x)
}
}
```

Comment: You want a normal distribution with a mean of 2 and a sd of 2 but no negatives?  That doesn't sound like a normal distribution any more... Why not `x <- rnorm(50, 2, 2); x[x > 0][1:5]` Or if you really don't care about the distribution:  `abs(rnorm(5, 2, 2))`!

Comment: I am not interested in the distribution. It is just an example so that I can adjust the code to my project.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you wanted to do, but your code works fine. You will end up with a variable x that has no negative values. (the for loop is unnecessary though and the print(x) doesn't indicate your final result which may be what's confusing you.

Comment: @DunderChief, I still see negative values though. Does it produce positive values only? If so, can you please share it here?

Comment: I guess the problem was with `for` and `print`. I have got what I want. Cheers :)

Comment: I vote for `x <- abs(rnorm(5,2,2))`  I mean, really...

Comment: @Carl, I am afraid I do not agree with you because it is true that my code and `abs(rnorm(5,2,2))` generate positive values only. However, my values are still normally distributed because the code picks the positive ones only. However,  `x <- abs(rnorm(5,2,2))` values may not be

Comment: I rather doubt your first claim there. Which is to say it's easily disproved by running any sort of test.  Try `qqplot` , for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code works. You're probably getting confused by the print(x) which doesn't represent the end result

```
repeat {
    x <- rnorm(5,2,2)
    if ((length(which(x<0)))==0){break}
}
x
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure why you do that or what you want to achieve exactly, but if you want to sample 100 values iteratively from a (2,2) normal distribution and repeat until all the values are positive, you can do something like :

```
v <- rnorm(100,2,2)
nb <- sum(v<0)
while (nb>0) {
  v[v<0] <- rnorm(nb,2,2)
  nb <- sum(v<0)
}
```

Comment: thank you. It works, but I need to do it with `repeat` and `şf`. Can you please do this by using `repeat` and `if` if possible? I will use this code in my project. So, the normal distribution is just for example.

Comment: Is it an homework ? By the way, I'm sure you could replace the `while` with `repeat` and `if` quite easily...

Comment: Yes it is. I know I am making a silly mistake, but could not figure out what it is

Comment: Done it guys. Thanks a million :)